# Eclipse NodeJS project code hint

Tags: eclipse, node.js, nodeclipse

I am working on a new Node project using Eclipse 4.3.1, and I have installed Nodeclipse 0.10.0. In the nodeclipse.org website there is a picture that shows some code hints with description etc. I need help making that work because I'm having trouble coding without these hints since this is my first Node project. Thank you

Comment: Some of the code hinting works such as when I type "fs." but I would like it to work for the functions that are in the node_module folder.

Comment: Do you Ctrl+Space and Ctrl+Shift+Space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nodeclipse has code hint with description (for JSDT Editor since 0.10, for TextEditor based Editor since 0.9) only for base Node.js modules.

[image]
<sub>(source: [nodeclipse.org](http://www.nodeclipse.org/img/Completion-for-base-Node.js-modules.PNG))</sub>

It is accessible with <kbd>Ctrl+Space</kbd> or <kbd>Alt+/</kbd>(for right hand)

Code completion without icons comes from `completion.json` that can be overwritten.

For other modules there is `completion.json` extended structure proposed:

```
{
    "completions": [
        {
            "trigger": "mymodule.doit();",
            "type": "method", // maybe also "event", "class" or "property"
            "name": "mymodule.doit",
            "desc": "the only method in some imaginary module"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am the author of advanced code hints in Nodeclispe (and lead the project currently). I will work on integrating such additional code hint metadata in Nodeclipse, but I will not work on creating such .json files. So it is matter whether there will be volunteers to work on specific modules support.

For any further questions and proposal create [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/issues).

Answer (score -1):

I had a lot of problems making eclipse work for web projects - than i discovered

1. Sublime - http://www.sublimetext.com/ (free)
2. Webstorm from JetBrains http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/ ($$)